# jquery function retrieves all elements rather than specific element

Tags: jquery, dom

I use the following function to retrieve the sentence from ul's after a user sorts the order and clicks to check the result. My problem is that the script finds the  sentences contained in all uls and not only the specific one clicked.

```
    const answer = {
                Q1: "I can't play piano",
                Q2: "The moon is a green balloon"                    
                };
const QNo = 2; 

function checkOrd() {
        // finds all instances of ul id: need to find one at a time and check only question clicked

        $('#quiz').find('ul').each(function() {
            let sentenceId = $(this).attr('id');
            //sentenceId is a str variable therefore must be applied as '#' + sentenceId to correctly function as id
            sentence = $.map($('#' + sentenceId + ' li'), function(element) {return $(element).text()}).join(' ');

            if (sentence == answer[sentenceId]) {
            alert('OK!') // message must be in quotes
                } else {
            alert('nope!')
            }

        });

    };
```

THe HTML:

```
    <div id = "quiz">
<ul class= "scramble" id = "Q1">
<li>I</li>
<li>piano</li>
<li>can't</li>
<li>play</li>
<button onclick ="checkOrd();">Check</button>
</ul>


<ul class="scramble" id = "Q2" >
<li>moon</li>
<li>green</li>
<li>is</li>
<li>balloon</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>The</li>
<button onclick ="checkOrd();">Check</button>
</ul>

</div>
```

I have tried looping, but all that does is repeat the function. Is there a way to link each button uniquely to the question/answer pair adjacent?  The problem seems to me to be with `sentence = $.map($('#' + sentenceId + ' li'), function(element) {return $(element).text()}).join(' ');` which retrieves all uls because of the way it is written. I don't have the knowledge to change it appropriately. I am not even convinced that I have asked the question itelligently!

Comment: The first thing you should fix is that `<button>` is not a valid child of a `<ul>` ( https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-ul-element ).  Secondly, you either need to change your `onclick="checkOrd();"` to `onclick="checkOrd(this);"` so the element clicked is passed in, or remove the inline bindings and use a logical binding instead that will pass in the event that you can get the element off of (event.target).  Once you get the element, you can use `closest('ul')` to get the related list and then proceed from there to get the nested li elements.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand how to do what you suggest. Will need to study your answer as well as the document to which you referred. Thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your code and converted to jQuery since you were using it already.

```js
const answer = {
                Q1: "I can't play piano",
                Q2: "The moon is a green balloon"                    
                };
const QNo = 2; 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".btn-click",function(){
        let sentenceId = $(this).closest("ul").attr('id');
        let sentence = $.map($(this).closest("ul").find("li"), function(element) {return $(element).text()}).join(' ');
        alert(sentence + "\n" + answer[sentenceId]);
        if (sentence == answer[sentenceId]) {
            alert('OK!') // message must be in quotes
                } else {
            alert('nope!')
            }
});


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "quiz">
<ul class= "scramble" id = "Q1">
<li>I</li>
<li>piano</li>
<li>can't</li>
<li>play</li>
<button type="button" class ="btn-click">Check</button>
</ul>


<ul class="scramble" id = "Q2" >
<li>moon</li>
<li>green</li>
<li>is</li>
<li>balloon</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>The</li>
<button type="button" class ="btn-click">Check</button>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: THanks for this. Will study and try to implement. Will vote tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var string='';
$('#Q1 > li, #Q2 > li').click(function(){
string+=$(this).text()+" ";
})

const answer = {
                Q1: "I can't play piano",
                Q2: "The moon is a green balloon"                    
                };
const QNo = 2; 

function checkOrd() {
  if(string.split(" ").join('')==answer.Q1.split(" ").join('') || string.split(" ").join('')==answer.Q2.split(" ").join(''))
  {alert("Yes");string=''}
  else
  {
  alert("No");string=''}
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "quiz">
<ul class= "scramble" id = "Q1">
<li>I</li>
<li>piano</li>
<li>can't</li>
<li>play</li>
<button onclick ="checkOrd();">Check</button>
</ul>


<ul class="scramble" id = "Q2" >
<li>moon</li>
<li>green</li>
<li>is</li>
<li>balloon</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>The</li>
<button onclick ="checkOrd();">Check</button>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: trouble is that with the "real" application that I want to use this for ( a language tutor for personal use) there will be many more questions that the two that i used in my question

Comment: It can be scaled up easily, just you have to assign a separate a button for every question, which will check the answers for that question only and using the if statement for individual questions. As we are dealing with patterns you have to do it. It will be lengthy but clean.